# empty Javascript function? What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, raphael

So the short version, what I don't understand is this line of code:

```
(new Function("paper", "window", "document", cd.value)).call(paper, paper);
```

The long version, look at these functions:

```
window.onload = function () {
            var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
            var btn = document.getElementById("run");
            var cd = document.getElementById("code");

            (btn.onclick = function () {
                paper.clear();
                paper.rect(0, 0, 640, 480, 10).attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "none"});
                try {
                    (new Function("paper", "window", "document", cd.value)).call(paper, paper);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message || e);
                }
            })();
        };
```

This code is from Raphael playground, which mean it implements the raphael library. So the single line of code at the top that I don't understand (it's inside the try/catch expression), suppose to copy the code that user enter that is stored inside cd.value into the function. But how is that possible?

You can visit the page here: http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you understand what `new Function()` does? It is similar to `eval()` in that it takes a string of javascript code - it uses that string to define a function. So the line you posted would be equivalent to doing:

```
(function(paper,window,document){
  /* the code in the cd.value string goes here */
}).call(paper,paper);
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function

Answer (score 2):

The Function class constructor

`functionName = new Function("function code should be written here");`

This construct evaluates the code as a string, and is much slower than assigning anonymous functions. It should only be used in places where it is actually needed.

The Function class constructor with parameters

`functionName = new Function("varName","varName2","etc.","function code");`

It looks like `cd.value()` provides a string with javascript code that is going to be parsed and compiled. Later you call it...

You should check how the code in `cd.value` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically creating a new function object with a dynamic body... the best way I can explain it is like this:

```
function (paper, window, document) where {} = cd.value;
```

Here's a resource to read more: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The `Function` function creates a new function instance with the last parameter as the code of the function.

So it basically does the same as:

```
eval("function(paper,window,document){"+cd.value+"}").call(paper, paper);
```

The `call` method simply calls the function with the items in the `paper` array for arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `Function` are the named parameters of the function, and then the body of the function. In this case, you have an element whose id is `code` and the `value` attribute on that element is some Javascript code. Consider that you have this HTML somewhere in your document:

```
<textarea id="code">
  var a = "foo";
  var b = "bar";

  alert(a+b);
</textarea>
```

Now, your code example, if run against this `code` element, would create the following function:

```
function(paper, window, document) {
  var a = "foo";
  var b = "bar";

  alert(a+b);
}
```

You can take a look at [the Mozilla Development Center's docs on Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function) to get a fuller explanation about how the `Function` object works.